# Why are my ListViewItem animations getting stuck when clicking?

Tags: uwp, transition

I have a UWP ListView with ListViewItems which I'm trying to animate when clicking on them. At the end of my sliding animation the pre-defined "tilt" animation is not finishing (like it's stuck).

Here is the animation I'm referring to that's not finishing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/motion-pointer

It's built into the ListViewItem style and I'd like to keep it, but not sure why it's not finishing the up animation.

[image]
[image]
 Here is the code I'm using to perform my animations which are working as expected:

```cs
private async void UIElement_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_lastListViewItem != null)
    {
        var resetTask = _lastListViewItem.Offset(0, 0, 500, 0, EasingType.Sine, EasingMode.EaseIn).StartAsync();
        await resetTask;
    }

    var listViewItem = LibrariesListView.ContainerFromItem(LibrariesListView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;

    _lastListViewItem = listViewItem;

    if (listViewItem != null)
    {
        var animateTask = listViewItem.Offset(-(float)EndXPosition, 0, 500, 0, EasingType.Sine, EasingMode.EaseIn).StartAsync();
        await animateTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you exactly. Do you want to finish title animation at the end of your animation? or you want to disable the tilt animation or etc.? 
I think a good solution should be to change the default style <Template> of the ListViewItem. You can add/remove/change animations there easily.

Comment: Sorry, I cut the animation off at the end. I'll re-upload a new one to demonstrate what  I'm talking about. I'm animating using TransformX to move the list items left and right. But the tilt animation doesn't quite finish when it slides to the left. You can barely see it at the end of the gif before it repeats. The list view item is still slightly tilted like it's not finishing the animation.

Comment: @AliNGame, I've updated my post with a better animation and a still image pointing to what I'm talking about. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please create a little repro of your list view and the way you implemented your animation? I will be able to help you better.

Comment: .StartAsync() creating a thread safe issue? Could async actions still be running, before animations are finished?

Comment: @Going-gone Nope, that was my first instinct as well. So I'm not 100% what the root cause is, but after editing a copy of the template for ListViewItem and removing the PointerDownThemeAnimation from the StoryBoards it resolved the issue. Maybe a bug with the template/animation because it works just like it should now.